# Compiled Qt 5 from Source, how do I change an old project to use the newly generated library?

Tags: qt, qt5

I compiled Qt from source, as explained in this link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html

At the end of the guide, there is no further instructions on how to use the newly generated files on an old project.  My old project still references the downloaded Qt files when I open the project in Qt Creator.

Building from source does not seem to generate a new QtCreator.

I tried going into Project mode using the regular QtCreator, and changing the files used there, but they seem to be unchangeable.

Comment: read https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html

Comment: Thanks! That did it.  I had looked under Tools->Options but somehow missed "Kits" :\  
They should really link to that document at the end of the "build from resources" document.

Comment: What do you get when you click on "Kits" ?, it shows an image of your progress.